Is it possible to use this "fixed-IP" sensor device using 802.11ah bridges to a "fixed-IP" computer?
I have a [closed source] sensor device connected on a survey drone which uses an Ethernet interface. For connecting in to computer, the manufacturer manual says:

Make sure the unit is connected to the host computer directly with an Ethernet cable. Alternatively both the unit and the host computer must be connected to the same local network with IP addresses in the range of 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.255. Make sure no other computer or device in the network has the IP address 192.168.1.100.

Then the manual instructs me to Change my computer's Ethernet from DHCP to IPv4 with fixed address of 192.168.1.99
This way the device connects to my computer and their provided program connects to it (my sensor has the IP of 192.168.1.111). I tried to sniff it using Wireshark and found out they simply talk using UDP packets.
However, we need this device to be on a drone at least 300 meters away, so we tried to test low-cost Halow bridges (a pair of TX and RX, documentation below).
I tested the bridges (TX to modem router for internet and RX to my computer) to test if I'm able to access internet; it was successful and I could get access to some sites (oddly, some websites didn't load including stackexchange.com).
But when connecting the bridge between my PC and Sensor (TX-RX, and RX-TX) the program can't find the sensor.
Also If I connect the sensor using this bridge to router (TX router, RX sensor), and connect my computer using WiFi to router, the program still can't get access to sensor (didn't change my computer IP on wireless adapter to fixed value).

The folder containing both documentations is here.
I'm not aware if the bridge devices or the sensor device have Auto MDI-X or not.


It sounds like the bridge is changing the subnet.  Can you confirm the IP address of the sensor after you connect it to the sensor? There is a very good chance the device has a static configuration.  I am not clicking unknown documentation links to understand more about the sensor itself.

I've messed with one of these, and its just a simple bridge there's no 'obvious' reason why your usecase shouldn't work, other than maybe latency
